Movie where a woman in an apartment experiments on corpses with a syringe, learns to possess people, and then takes over the protagonist's girlfriend
The movie seems to take place in an apartment with a man and a woman, likely his wife or girlfriend; I can't remember.
The villain, a different woman, is taking the bodies of people who died in the apartment and then sticking some machine on them that looks like a huge, thick metallic syringe that sucks their souls and looks like a blue glowing wisp.
I remember her taking the bodies on one of those beds with wheels that we see in hospitals. Maybe she worked at the morgue or something; I'm not sure.
In the beginning, she fails, but once the old lady dies, she succeeds. I remember her henchman/thug asking why she thinks it will work this time, and she comments that the old woman never left the apartment in years, so her soul is still there or something along those lines.
I think the protagonist does kill her or she dies somehow, but by this point, she has already learned to possess and takes over his lover.
I think she, in his wife's body, asks him to buy some castle or mansion (I'm not sure, but I think it belonged to her family in the past or something) and they move there. Eventually, the protagonist finds out.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

It was shown in school by a teacher. I'm not sure why, but that teacher would sometimes show movies or series. One of the series was Merlin, but this version was set in a modern context. Sadly, I can't even remember the teacher's face or gender.

In roughly which year did you see this?

Unfortunately, I don't remember it well. If I had to guess, it was between 2006 and 2012, but I'm not certain. I don't know if the teacher was showing recent movies, and I believe the CGI was fairly basic not crappy but basic, so it's likely an older film. If I remember correctly, the villain was a pale woman with black hair, and she didn't appear to be old.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lazarus_Effect_(2015_film) might be a bit too recent.

Sorry, but I don't think it's the Lazarus effect. It wasn't a team of scientists; it looked more clandestine. It was her and a male henchman who was clearly a side character. Her possession resembled turning into a dark mist and flying into another person's body; it was something learned. Also, when I say she was using a syringe-like machine, it was more for studying souls rather than injecting herself with anything.

This is The Tomb (2009).
It's loosely based on Edgar Allan Poe's 1838 short story, Ligeia, and the film was originally titled Edgar Allan Poe's Ligeia before being renamed.
The protagonist, Jonathan Merrick, is a young literature professor teaching at an American university. He's engaged to an actress named Rowena, but finds himself irresistibly drawn to a beautiful grad student named Ligeia and eventually leaves Rowena for her.
Unbeknownst to him, Ligeia is terminally ill and, with the assistance of a thuggish male admirer named Eddie, has been secretly murdering people in order to capture their souls, using a combination of science and magic. Each victim is brought to the autopsy room of the university at night, where she injects them with a large metal syringe containing an experimental formula and captures their soul within a transparent cylinder attached to a muzzle placed over their mouth.



Her ultimate goal is to strengthen her own soul by binding other souls to it, thereby enabling her to transfer it into another living person's body and gain their remaining lifespan. One of her victims is an old woman who lives across the hall in the same apartment building as her, leading to the following dialogue exchange:

EDDIE: She's dead. What makes you think this will be any different?
LIGEIA: She only left her apartment twice a month for years. Her spirit will be close.

As Ligeia's health declines, Jonathan buys the old manor she was born and raised in by the Black Sea in Ukraine, and they move there together and get married. However, it turns out she's been using magic to make him love her, and as she weakens, so too does her hold over him. He finds out what she's been up to and leaves her, hoping to win back Rowena. Ligeia then commits suicide and transfers her soul into Rowena.
You can view some shots of the soul extraction process at around the 0:48 mark in the trailer below.



